# Opening a file picker in any browser crashes the browser

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser, crash, file-chooser

In Windows 7 32-bit, in any browser (chrome, IE, firefox, opera) if I open a file picker either by using the main menu option e.g. 'open page' or 'save page as', or if a file picker appears from interacting with a website e.g. 'download pdf', then the entire browser instantly crashes and shuts downs. With Chrome, it then offers to restart, and all tabs are restored.

I've tried:

- disabling all addons
- shutting down all other programs

This is a recent issue. It only happens in browsers, not in other apps like MS Word or Notepad++. It may be due to the recent installation of some other software, but I don't want to uninstall everything just to find out - if someone can give me a clue as to what might cause this, I could hone in on the culprit.

I've recently installed:

- wuala (i disabled the file system integration)
- qq instant messenger
- hipchat

I'd be grateful if anyone could shed some light on why this is happening, or give me some steps to try and identify the issue.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a Common Controls DLL incompatibility.